# Create a screenshot from a page

Tags: cordova, pdf, ionic-framework

I would like to know if there are any options to generate a screenshot image (pdf is acceptable) from an ionic Cordova page.

Basically, it would be possible to just send the data to the backend and render a pdf using JasperReport, but I am considering a different approach:

Basically, the data is a barcode and a line of text. So, it would be quite simple to just generate a page with the barcode using barcode-scanner and add whatever text I need and generate an image/pdf from that page.

That page will then be shared using share to a Bluetooth printer configured on the device which will print the file.

At the moment, I am trying to use this plugin> https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/native/screenshot/
I have followed the instructions for installations and use, but then I make the call I get the following error:

`TypeError: "navigator.screenshot is undefined"`

I would like to have some help in order to correctly use this plugin, as my code is exactly the same from the specified on the plugin page, but I get the error above.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone lands here, just note that the screenshot plugin doesn't support browser, and so when you run your app with `ionic serve`, you will get the same error I got.

By running through emulator or `ionic cordova run` it is going to work.